# Can't get parent page id

Tags: breadcrumb

I use the free-blog theme and I have created a menue:

```
Home
  page A
  page B
      Child page A
      Child page B
      Child page C
  Page C
      Child Post A
      Child Post B
```

Now I want to create a bread crump. like_
Home-> Page B -> Child page A

So far this is not so difficult. I can get the Child Page Id without problems but I can't get the parent page ID. It is always 0.

I tried it with

```
$post_id = get_queried_object_id();
$post    = get_post( $post_id );
$parent_link = get_permalink($post->post_parent); 
$parent_title = get_the_title($post->post_parent);
```

$post->post_parent is always 0

then I tried

```
$parents = get_post_ancestors( post_id );
```

but the parents count is 0 too. The same with

```
 wp_get_post_parent_id
```

So I wonder if I do something wrong when I created my menue. In the Child Post A I tried to select the category, but the parent value is still 0

Comment: By default if there's no parent page is selected, the `post_parent` will be `0`. You can consult this article, if you are in a wrong direction: http://dimox.net/wordpress-breadcrumbs-without-a-plugin/

Comment: Thank you for the link. I thought that when I have a menue like above then the "Child page A" hast automaticlly Page B as parent. If this is not so, how can I set Page B as parent of childpage A?

Comment: I just tried the code from your link but there I get only  bread crumb Home-Category-Child Page. But my Page B is not a category but a page because I want to publish informations on that page too

Comment: Probably a stupid question, but did you set parents for pages `Child page A`, `Child page B`, etc.? "Parent page" field in the quick edit or "Page attributes -> parent page" in the edit screen.

Comment: Thank you this was the problem. I'm new to Wordpress, I thought the parent is defined through the menue

Comment: @MayeenulIslam your link is suspect (I didn't hang around long enough to find out what it was)